# Set log destination via .htaccess

Tags: php, apache

I want to set error log destination via .htaccess

**Directory**

```
michael@michael:/var/www/html$ ls -la
total 1492
drwxr-xr-x 2 root    root       4096 дек  9 14:08 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root    root       4096 сен 13 15:23 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root        153 дек  9 14:08 2.php
-rw-r--r-- 1 root    root        235 дек  9 14:08 .htaccess
```

**.htaccess**

```
DirectoryIndex index.php

# supress php errors
php_flag display_startup_errors off
php_flag display_errors off
php_flag html_errors off

# enable PHP error logging
php_flag  log_errors on
php_value error_log  /var/tmp/PHP_errors.log
```

**2.php**

```
<p>Test</p>

<?php
   phpinfo();
   $message = "Trololo";
   $destination = "/var/tmp/my-errors.log";
   error_log ( $message, 3,  $destination );
?>
```

Result:
When I enter in URL http://localhost/2.php, in the shown php settings:

```
error_log    no value
```

[image: Error log: no value]

What can I do to investigate this problem?

Comment: Hi Trts - a quick bit of advice if I may. I notice that your questions are usually worded to "hand over" your work to readers. What I mean by this is rather than asking "How can I fix this", your questions are of the form "Please help me with it" or "Please help me understand this". Rightly or wrongly, readers may interpret this as excessively needy, or possibly that you have given up and want other people to finish your project.

Comment: I have written [more information here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/391945/472495) on this theme, which may be useful. Put another way, you may have better/more responses if you make it clear that you still intend to do the bulk of the work.

Comment: On the theme of giving up and asking a question, you may also find it helpful, after posting a question, to carry on investigating the problem at hand. While it is tempting to let someone do it for you, sometimes the act of writing a question clarifies the problem in an authors mind to such a degree that they find they are able to solve it themselves.  This is another aspect of developing personal agency and self-reliance, IMO.